# Integral calculation/transformation $\varphi_n= 2x\varphi_n$

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, chebyshev-polynomials

Please help with below integral transformation.

\begin{align*}
T_n(x) & = \cos(n\cos^{-1} x)\\
w(t) & = (1 - x^2)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\\
\varphi_n(x) & = \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{T_n(t) - T_n(x)}{t - x}w(t)~dt\\
\end{align*}
How to prove:
$$\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{2tT_n(t) - 2xT_n(x)}{t - x}w(t)~dt = 2x\varphi_n(x)$$

Comment: Can you offer any thoughts, describe particular difficulties, or give any other context for this problem?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020), 
[here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559), 
[here](//meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/1773) and 
[here](/help/notation).

Comment: Yes, the difficulty here is, I am not sure how to deduce from the left to the right. This is an integral from approximation theory (which I think context is neglect-able). Just for more information, Tn(x) is the chebyshev polynomials, w(x) is the weight function of the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2tT_{n}\left(t\right)-2xT_{n}\left(x\right)}{t-x}w\left(t\right)dt=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2xT_{n}\left(t\right)-2xT_{n}\left(x\right)}{t-x}w\left(t\right)dt$$ can be rewritten $$\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{2tT_{n}\left(t\right)-2xT_{n}\left(x\right)-2xT_{n}\left(t\right)+2xT_{n}\left(x\right)}{t-x}w\left(t\right)dt=0\rightarrow2\int_{-1}^{1}T_{n}\left(t\right)w\left(t\right)dt=0$$
 so your equality is true iff $$2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos\left(n\cos^{-1}\left(t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}dt=0$$
 in fact $$2\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{\cos\left(n\cos^{-1}\left(t\right)\right)}{\sqrt{1-t^{2}}}dt=\frac{2\sin\left(\pi n\right)}{n}=0.$$

Comment: You are an hero! Will check it tomorrow. Good night! :) (Sorry for the chit chat LOL)